# Table View Crashing When Accessing Array of Dicitonarys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

When my table view loads, it accesses several delegate methods. When I configure the cell, I have it calling this method (where "linkedList" is an array of dictionarys):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    VUWIManager *vuwiManager = [VUWIManager sharedVuwiManager];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSLog(@"TESTZOMGOFDSOJFDSJFPODJSAPFDS");
    cell.textLabel.text = [[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

It crashes at the line `cell.textLabel.text = [[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` - I know I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what it is. Again, linkedList is a NSMutableArray of NSDictionarys.

Edit: if I call `cell.textLabel.text = [[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` it returns:
`{
    IP = "192.168.17.1";
    desc = "description";
}`
 in the debugger. Just thought I'd give a little bit of formatting details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign an object `NSDictionary` to `cell.textLabel.text`, which must be passed a `NSString`.

Did you want :

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                        [[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.textLabel.text = s;
```

?

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me. I can't believe I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an NSString * to an NSDictionary * will likely result in a crash when it tries to access any string methods that are not implemented in the dictionary. If you want that string you are logging add a call to description.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting cell.textLabel.text to a NSDictionary instead of an NSString. If linkedList is an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries, then you need to add on objectForKey:@"String key" to access the string

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[vuwiManager linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"STRING_KEY_HERE"];
```